# getting started with flyway for one with no java experience

Tags: flyway

I am interested in testing flyway and if I am not wrong I read that it supports db changes both through java and SQL. I am a dba and familiar with SQL but not java.
I read through the “Getting Started” page and wanted to try out the sample application available under the “Downloads tab” link however I couldn’t find any readme document explaining the available downloads which appeared to contain .jar files.

Q) is there an instruction manual for a newbies to explain how to put together this sample application?

Q) can one uses flyway without knowing java? If yes, please provide any how-to url/notes/documents available. If not do you have any how-to for one to get started with java just enough to operate this tool?

Thanks Bob

Comment: If you want this question deleted, please flag it.

Comment: JBCP's answer is excellent.  You don't need Java at all.  We have a Java application, and still use the command line exclusively for DB updates.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might find the command line tool useful:

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/

As it says on the website:

> The Flyway command-line tool is meant for users who
>
> - do not run their applications on the JVM
> - wish to migration their database from the command-line without having to install Maven

You may need to browse the source code to figure out some more details:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway

Although I think you should be able to adapt the regular documentation to the CLI option.

Try starting here:

http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/existingDatabaseSetup.html